# how to read server address from a json config file and setting that parameter to ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to add server link in separate config file so I can change it easily

```
var RPiService = {};
var RPi_Url = "http://192.168.10.75:1337/"
```

I want to add above address in separate config file so I can change it easily

```
RPiService = {
  changeDeviceState: function (state) {
    //+ "?state=" + state
    var jqXhr = $.ajax({
      url: RPi_Url + "?state=" + state,
      crossDomain: true,
      datatype: "jsonp",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

    return jqXhr;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.env` file in the root of your project folder to define environment variables the are set on project run time. That way, you can define multiple environments (i.e. development, test, production) from which to run your application in. In the same file, you can include the value you wish per environment. An example looks like:

Access these variable with

```
console.log(process)
```

or

```
console.log(process.env)
```

to see your woking output. Best part of this method is that anything you define as an environment variable is completely hidden within the application.